# Configure GDAL to use Open JPEG 2000 library

Tags: gdal, jpeg-2000

`gdalinfo --formats` shows one entry for the JPEG 2000:

`JPEG2000 -raster,vector- (rwv): JPEG-2000 part 1 (ISO/IEC 15444-1), based on Jasper library`

I don't want to use the Jasper library. I want to use the Open JPEG 2000 library. How do I configure GDAL to use a different library for a particular raster format?

Comment: It is an option that must be selected when GDAL is compiled from the sources. You can't add OpenJPEG support to the build that you have but you must either acquire another build or compile GDAL yourself. What is your operating system?

Comment: Thank you. I'm developing on a Mac, but the system will be deployed on Linux and Windows

Comment: PS: if you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it